# Привязка кнопки к функции

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Как привязать кнопку к функции `public function delete()`. Нужно чтобы кнопка из `view\welcom_messege` была привязана к функции `public function delete()` из `controllers\Welcom.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понимаю то это должна быть кнопка отправления формы а сама форма должна отправляться на соответствующий action delete.

Не зная структуру вашего URL точно не скажу но чтото вроде этого

```
<? $form = ActiveForm::begin(['action' =>['post/delete'],'method' => 'post',]); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'post_id') ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('Удалить') ?>
<? ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```